# Connection to the internet keeps dropping on Acer netbook

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

I've been trying to connect from my netbook (ehh, I know, I am working on getting a better computer) to my Wi-Fi and it loads then it drops it.

Answer (score 0):

If Ubuntu didn't detect it it's probably not supported, I had an unsupported ralink card in my laptop that i had to replace with an intel wifi link minipcie card, Now wireless works fine for me.

This is the card i bought [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009AO8I1A)

Answer (score 0):

i use an acer aspire one with xubuntu 10.13. i have a similar problem sometimes. my network indicator will display that i am connected to a network but when i try and load a webpage, it says not available. i can fix this by:

*opening network connections, 
 deleting the connection, 
 then i disable networking, 
 then re-enable networking and reconnect to the network that was giving me trouble*

then everything works fine.